# REPORTS-Participant List 4.6.10

Tags: civireport

I edited the report for our needs, which is a primarily a list of attendees.  We only require the following for our reporting needs:

Name
Organization
Event
Status
Start Date 
End Date

I cannot get anything when I preview the report.

I input in filter:

Participant Status: Attended

Participant Role:  Attendee

Event Type:  I clicked on all the events I would need attendee info for

then I input a start and end date

I get no names at all - blank

Under columns I checked off what I needed as well

?????

I am not a programmer.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem - it's a bug in the current version of the
Participant list Count Report which should be fixed in the next release. The bug report is here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17485

It's the participant role filter that is causing the problem. If you de-select the participant role, you should see all the participants. Depending on what else you need from the report, you might be better off using the 'Event Participant Report (List)' report.